# Error installing MVVMCross from nuget into a PCL

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

When I try to install MvvmCross into a new PCL I receive an error. The console log is below:

```
Package Manager Console Host Version 2.5.40416.9020

Type 'get-help NuGet' to see all available NuGet commands.

PM> install-package MvvmCross
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack (≥ 3.0.6)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore (≥ 3.0.6)'.
``Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport (≥ 3.0.6)'.
Installing 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.6'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.6'.
Installing 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.6'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.6'.
Installing 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack 3.0.6'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.StarterPack 3.0.6'.
Installing 'MvvmCross 3.0.6'.
Successfully installed 'MvvmCross 3.0.6'.
Adding 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.6' to Clevermed.Badger.Mobile.Core.
Uninstalling 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.6'.
Successfully uninstalled 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.6'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: supportedFrameworks
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package MvvmCross
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I'm using Profile104 as described in http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html

This is a similar but separate error to [MvvMCross 3.0.6 Nuget package installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529794/mvvmcross-nuget-package-installation-issue)

Furthermore, if I right click on the solution and 'Manage NuGet packages' I receive the error 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: supportedFrameworks'.

Any ideas how I can debug this further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how, but I had an empty Profile104 folder in C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile

Probably a left over form my first attempts.

Removing this empty directory allowed the installation to complete without error.

Comment: That works. But not for every type of projects. Profile104 references to "Portable Library" (which is consedered as "Application.Core" project basis). And if there is no such profile, then you can not add anything to its type of project at all.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue while installing MvvMCross 3.0.6 Nuget package. I had raised a similar question [MvvMCross 3.0.6 Nuget package installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529794/mvvmcross-3-0-6-nuget-package-installation-issue)

So I followed Stuarts suggestion and referred the MvvmCross dll's directly in the project which worked like a charm. You can download the MvvMCross code from https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross.

Comment: Thanks. For me the issue was a Profile104 folder in the v4.5 (rather than v4.0) directory

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but what version of NuGet are you running?

To get the MonoTouch and MonoAndroid support (and some of the Portable support) you will need Nuget 2.5 installed

Comment: I'm running 2.5.40416.9020

Comment: Updating Nuget in Visual Studio 2012 fixed the issue for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a side note (and dunno if it's going to fix this): you can check your nuget version in Tools > Extensions and Updates. Here you can view the list of your installed packages, as well as their version.

Also, if you nuget package manager is out of date, it will show up under the 'Updates' category.

... on the other hand, you package manager console says it's version 2.5.something, so I'm guessing you're up to date on that one.

Comment: Thanks Gitte, I'm running 2.5.4.

Comment: And your PCL, which targetframeworks do you have checked? As in: are you targetting 7.1 or 7.5 for windows phone? Ie. If I myself pick 7.1 I receive a similar (but slightly different) error.

Comment: Turns out I had created a Profile104 folder in the v4.5 framework folder. This was causing Nuget to error.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but could there be an issue with the NuGet package MvvmCross.PortableSupport ?

Click the image to see it in full resolution...

[image: Target Framework unrecognized?]

Also check the NuGet docs for details on the supported Target Framework variables: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Matching_Assembly_Version_to_the_Target_Framework_of_a_Project

Comment: I think this package is the issue however it does target frameworks that are only installed with Xamarin. Therefore I'm not sure if that error is to be expected.

Comment: Then it seems logical that the NuGet VS extension fails package installation for that package. However, that dependency should be conditional in a dependency group: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuspec-reference#Specifying_Dependencies_in_version_2.0_and_above The dependent package should specify that condition, so the issue is in the dependent package as far as I can tell.