# Xamarin: Unable to add HotTuna.StarterPack

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to install the MVVMCross.HotTuna.StarterPack on my Xamarin (Mac) Solution using the NuGet, but i ain't successful. The package was installed in the Xamarin.Android project successfully but while i try the same to do with the iOS and PCL project, it doesn't add. Any Idea on whats going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That nuget package requires nuget 2.5 which isn't yet finished/released for Xamarin Studio - track https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin/issues/13 for updates

It will also probably require fixes from Xamarin - they've not yet released PCL support, but it is in development. You can ask their forum and/or support for updates on this.

In the meantime:

- you can develop for MvvmCross using VS on the PC - see http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com/
- you can develop using binaries (not nuget) on the Mac - see http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/05/xamarin-studio-quick-run-through-for.html

For Xamarin.Mac/MonoMac support, there's no PCL support currently available - so the only way to get this working currently is to fork the MvvmCross solution and to compile the PCL libraries for the appropriate Mac project. For more on current .Mac issues, track and/or contribute to: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3733/playing-with-pcls

Comment: First, i tried it in the VS and i faced [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539385/error-installing-mvvmcross-from-nuget-into-a-pcl) problem and hence, unable to solve that, i switched to Mac. Thanks for your reply. I shall try using the binaries.

Comment: Yes, but i don't find any empty folder in my case. 
As per your comment above, in [this link](http://slodge.blogspot.com/2013/05/xamarin-studio-quick-run-through-for.html), i heard that using PCL is harder. Isn't it harder in VS then?

Comment: In which case you don't have the same problem.

Comment: The resolved answer to the problem was removing the empty Profile104 folder, but i don't see any empty Profile104 folder in my system.

Comment: The OP on that other question had a problem and solved it. If their solution does not work for you, then you **do not have** the same problem.