# MvvmCross 3.0.8.1 Nuget Installation error

Tags: mono, nuget, mvvmcross, printer-control-language

I am creating a cross-platform project for android and ios devices. I am creating a PCL on Visual Studio 2012 (I am doing as http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He6QvnLsPUA&feature=youtu.be&t=13m13s).
But when I try to install new version of MvvmCross by Nuget, I have the following error:

*Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport (≥
3.0.8.1)'. Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.8.1'. Successfully installed 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore 3.0.8.1'. Successfully uninstalled 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.8.1'. Install failed. Rolling back... Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.8.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile104', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

Can anyone tell me why I get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- [MvvMCross 3.0.6 Nuget package installation issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529794/mvvmcross-3-0-6-nuget-package-installation-issue/)
- [Error installing MVVMCross from nuget into a PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539385/error-installing-mvvmcross-from-nuget-into-a-pcl)

Most likely you have an old version of nuget and/or are lacking the PCL xml files for touch and/or droid (http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html)