# Install MvvmCross 3.0.7 NuGet package using Xamarin 4.7.6 (Alpha) fails on my setup

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

Reminder: I'm using Xamarin (Droid) 4.7.6. **Alpha** version!

Creating a new Xxx.Core MvvmCross library:
1) Start new PCL library project
2) Select target frameworks: .Net 4.5, SL 4+, WP7.5+, .Net Store, Mono Android, VS MonoTouch
3) Install NuGet package for MvvmCross v3 - Hot Tuna

Fails:

*Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport 3.0.7'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-win+net45+MonoAndroid16+sl40+net10+wp71', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

Temporary solution:

Start by selecting only target frameworks: .Net 4.5, SL 4+, WP7.5+. Then install MvvmCross package (install fine). Then go to project properties and add the other target frameworks.

After this small hickup, no further issues.

Comment: do any of the solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529794/mvvmcross-3-0-6-nuget-package-installation-issue/16673624#16673624 help? Especially deleting any VSMonoTouch files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `net10` part of your error line makes me particularly suspicious that you have some old VSMonoTouch xml files around.

To solve this you will probably need to:

- remove the old VSMonoTouch file
- add a new Xamarin.iOS MonoTouch file (mine are http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/my-current-pcl-setup-in-visual-studio.html - but these may change when Xamarin launches its PCL support)
- restart Vs
- maybe start a new project or solution (I'm not sure where Vs caches its PCL list)